# Can't get the text of a div with xpath query

Tags: php

I am trying to get the text of a div and I am using the following `PHP` code

```
$directions = $xpath->query('//div[contains(@class,"directions")]/text()');
var_dump($directions->item(0));
```

On this `HTML`

```
<div class="directions" itemprop="recipeInstructions">
    <h4>Directions</h4>
    Preheat oven to 350 degrees. Cook broccoli according to package directions. 
    Drain liquid from the broccoli and transfer to a round casserole dish. Dot broccoli with cubed butter and cheese.
    Mix crushed crackers with melted butter and cover broccoli mixture. 
    Bake for 30 minutes or until cheese is bubbly.<br /><br />
    SUGGESTION: You can assemble this dish a day or so ahead of time and store, covered, in the fridge until ready to bake.
</div>
```

But I get `null` value. Can anyone tell me how can U get the text of the div in the above HTML?
here is my script

```
<?php
$url = "https://www.therecipedepository.com/site-map/categories";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$xml = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$categories = new SimpleXmlElement($xml);
foreach($categories->children() as $urls){
    $url = $urls->loc;
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
    //Query the DOM
    $links = $xpath->query('//li[contains(@class,"recipe-item")]//a');
    //Display the results as in the previous example
    foreach($links as $link){
        $url_ = 'https://www.therecipedepository.com' . $link->getAttribute('href');
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url_);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $r = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        $dom_ = new DOMDocument;
        @$dom_->loadHTML($r);
        $xpath_ = new DOMXpath($dom_);
        $titres = $xpath_->query( '//h3[contains(@class, "recipe-name")]' );
        $prep_time = $xpath->query( '//li[contains(@class, "prep-time")]' );
        $cook_time = $xpath->query( '//li[contains(@class, "cook-time")]' );
        $servings = $xpath->query( '//li[contains(@class, "servings")]//span[contains(@itemprop,"recipeYield")]' );

        $ingredients = $xpath->query('//li[contains(@class,"ingredient")]');

        foreach($ingredients as $ingredient){
            $ingredient[] = $ingredient->nodeValue;
        }

        foreach($titres as $titre){
            $titres__[] = $titre->nodeValue;
        }

        $imgs = $xpath_->query( '//img[contains(@class, "recipe-image")]' );

        foreach ($imgs as $img) {
            $imgs__[] = $img->getAttribute('src');
        }

        $directions = $xpath->query("//div[@class='directions']");
        foreach($directions as $direction){
            echo $direction->nodeValue;
        }
        for($i=0;$i<sizeof($imgs__);$i++){
        echo $i.'-----------------------INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES("'.$titres__[$i].'","'.$imgs__[$i].'")<br>';
    }
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: How do you call the html file? Please post your script.

Comment: do you want to get all text inside this particular div?

Comment: The result `$directions` consists of 3 elements. You only look at the first, which contains only whitespace.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting `null`? and not an empty value?

Comment: Did you try `var_dump($directions->item(1));` ?

Comment: yes i am getting null even when i tried var_dump($directions->item(1)). i want to get all the text inside the div

Comment: sorry Nimeshka with echo $direction->item(0); i get an empty value not a null sorry. and i tried item(1) and it always gives me an empty value

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all text inside this div then you can try this code:

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$html = '<html><div class="directions" itemprop="recipeInstructions">
<h4>Directions</h4>
Preheat oven to 350 degrees. Cook broccoli according to package directions. Drain liquid from the broccoli and transfer to a round casserole dish. Dot broccoli with cubed butter and cheese.  Mix crushed crackers with melted butter and cover broccoli mixture. Bake for 30 minutes or until cheese is bubbly.<br />
<br />
SUGGESTION:  You can assemble this dish a day or so ahead of time and store, covered, in the fridge until ready to bake.  </div></html>';

$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$divVal = $xpath->query("//div[@class='directions']");
foreach($divVal as $div)
{
    echo $div->nodeValue;
}
```

**OUTPUT WILL BE**

> Directions Preheat oven to 350 degrees. Cook broccoli according to
>   package directions. Drain liquid from the broccoli and transfer to a
>   round casserole dish. Dot broccoli with cubed butter and cheese. Mix
>   crushed crackers with melted butter and cover broccoli mixture. Bake
>   for 30 minutes or until cheese is bubbly. SUGGESTION: You can assemble
>   this dish a day or so ahead of time and store, covered, in the fridge
>   until ready to bake.

Comment: thanks for your reply but how can i retrieve the portion of code of the div from the html document?

Comment: you meant from a separate html file?